# BoxDecoration colors not accepted in Flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I have an issue with a parameter.

I have got the following code from a tutorial:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0xff3C8CE7), const Color(0xff00EAFF)])),
```

The project is running fine on both platforms, but there is a warning at line:

```
colors: [const Color(0xff3C8CE7), const Color(0xff00EAFF)])),
```

This is the warning output at the Dart Analysis debug window:

[image]

I have searched for the right implementation of BoxDecoration and gradient colors and it says just the way I am doing it.

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, make sure you're using the `stable` or `beta` channel of flutter. To do so, run these commands:

1. `flutter channel stable`
2. `flutter upgrade`
3. `flutter clean`

Restart your IDE and try to run again.